# How to pass argument if event handler is assigned in initialization function?

Tags: javascript, html, prototypejs, structure

It is always good to separate presentation layer and behaviour between HTML and Javascript based on head first book.

They tell me not to do:

```
<textarea onclick="showAlert()"></textarea>
```

But instead, do below:

The example below separate the behaviour from HTML code (structure).

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = init;

function init() {
  $('txt_area').onclick = showAlert;
}

function showAlert(say) {
  alert(say);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="txt_area"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

This allows HTML (structure) to look clean and "behaviour" part is initialized in init() function when page loads. I understand that so far.

But then I wonder how am I supposed to pass an argument to showAlert() function???

Below does not work, it will call the showAlert() as soon as the page loads and this is not what I want to because it needs to be fired onclick.

```
function init() {
  $('txt_area').onclick = showAlert("hello");
}
```

Is it possible to pass arguments to showAlert() function but still separate the behaviour and structure?

**UPDATE**

Forgot to mention.. I'm using prototype.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your code in a function.

```
$('txt_area').onclick = function() {
    showAlert("hello");
};
```

Comment: Thanks, totally didn't think about it, js can do that!

Comment: @Reigel: I've tested the provided code and it seems to work just fine.

Comment: @masato-san - good for you. I find many error on that. first, `$('txt_area')` should be `$('#txt_area')`(with a `#`). second, `.onclick()` is a native JS, `$('#txt_area')` is a jQuery object. it should be `$('#txt_area').click()` XD

Comment: @Reigel - maybe this is not jQuery? it works fine in some frameworks - http://jsbin.com/ecihe4

Comment: @Reigel: I see.. my apology not mentioned framework, I'm using prototype.